# Paypal and REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws

From all resources that I have read about REST vs JAX-WS, the use of JAX-WS is recommended when a higher level of security is required.

If that is the case, I'm curious on why PayPal uses REST web service. Money transfer is a transaction which require a high level of security. Can anyone give their opinion on this?

EDIT:
If SSL is used anyway, then what sort of "security contract" does JAX-WS have over REST?

Comment: 'cause they do it over SSL?

Comment: then might as well have everything in REST?

Comment: That is a false statement. REST and SOAP over HTTP have the same security level when applying HTTPS. SOAP just allows you to clearly define certain standards such as Web services security from OASIS to the WSDL. REST services does not quiet have this capability yet ... I say yet because there is a WSDL artifact for REST which is a WADL however WADL files are not commonly used.

Comment: So could we say that security is not a reason choosing JAX-WS over REST? Choosing JAX-WS may be more about its other characteristics like being asychronous, stateful, limited bandwidth etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a JAX-WS vs REST discussion, per-se.  This is a SOAP vs. REST discussion.  JAX-WS is just the modern JavaEE framework for writing Java (SOAP) web service provider or client/consumer applications.

Various OASIS standards for SOAP, such as [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), as @Namphibian refers to, contain open specifications for:

- **Message integrity**: ensuring no 3rd party has tampered with the contents of the request/response, regardless of transport level (e.g. HTTPS) security used
- **Message confidentiality**: ensuring no 3rd party can read parts or all of the request/response, regardless of transport level security
- **Message non-repudiation**: usage of digital signatures within request/response messages that provide assurance (or remove ability to claim 'we didn't send it') that the sending party is in fact the party that created the message.

All of these are sometimes excruciatingly complex to implement (above the already-complex base SOAP specs).  However, they provide a degree of security that to my knowledge have no direct counterpart in RESTful services.  This is strictly speaking from an available open standard perspective.

REST is generally accepted as far easier to integrate with/consume, and if you're willing to bank all security on transport level (HTTPS) confidentiality, then you're good to go.

SOAP message-level security is designed to allow protection even if transport level security is breached or not used at all.